# Angular passing a value from child component to disable button in parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, output, eventemitter, disable

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the `@Output` and `EventEmitter` to pass a boolean value from the child component to the button in the parrent element to disable or enable it.

More specifically, I want that when the container with text is scrolled at the bottom (which is the child component) to pass the boolean value for a variable to the parent component which I can use with the `[disabled]` property.

The scroll calculation is already working, I'm only having trouble with the `@Output` and `EventEmitter`.

Here's the code:

this is the child component

```
@Output() buttonDisabledEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  scrolledToBottom() {
    if (
      // container is scrolled to bottom
    ) {
      this.buttonDisabledEvent.emit(false);
      // or something like this maybe?
      this.buttonDisabledEvent.emit(buttonDisabled = false);
    }
  }
```

the parent html

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="lobyco-btn lobyco-btn-primary"
  [disabled]="buttonDisabled" <--- I need the new value to be used here
>
  Accept
</button>
```

I hope it's clear enough what I need and apologies in advance if anything is unclear - I'll be checking back very soon and update if needed - thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **child-component** you say `this.buttonDisabledEvent.emit(false);`

Then you have to catch the event in the **ParentComponent HTML** like this:

```
<app-child (buttonDisabledEvent)="onButtonDisabled($event)"></app-child>

<button
  type="button"
  class="lobyco-btn lobyco-btn-primary"
  [disabled]="buttonDisabled" <--- I need the new value to be used here
>
  Accept
</button>
```

And the **ParentComponent TS** would read as follows:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  buttonDisabled = false;

  onButtonDisabled(buttonDisabled: boolean) {
    this.buttonDisabled = buttonDisabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Didn't even think to add the new EventEmitter listner to the parent component HTML. 

This is so simple and works great @kellermat ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you should configure the parent component by creating some method

for eg:
in parent.component.ts

```
button : boolean = true;

buttonDisable(event: boolean) {
this.button = false;
}
```

then configure the parent HTML component

for eg:

```
<button [disable]=buttonDisabledEvent="buttonDisable($event)" >BUTTON</button>
```